# Proving that a language having a particular CFG grammar is equivalent to a particular L

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

[image]

I think we need to prove that L(G) is a subset of L and then we need to prove that L is a subset of L(G).

For the first part, I think we need to say for any w in L(G) we have an even number of as and bs, we have 2 cases aSbS and bSaS, and we need to prove that those two can become awbw and bwaw respectively at a certain point. For the other part, I have no idea. I think we need to show that any w in L can be obtained with the CFG, but how to do that, I have no idea. Can someone flesh out a full proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing that your context-free gramma produces only strings with an equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s is easy. You start out with the non-terminal symbol $S$. That contains zero $a$'s and zero $b$'s. Now apply one of the productions \begin{eqnarray}
  S &\to& aSbS \\
  S &\to& bSaS \\
  S &\to& \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
Each production maintains the invariant that there are as many $a$'s as there are $b$'s, since they all introduce either exactly one $a$ and one $b$, or none at all.

For the other direction, you can use induction. You can obviously produce the zero-length string, using the production $S \to \epsilon$. You can also produce the two-character strings $ab$ and $ba$, which are the only two-character strings containing an equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s. Assume now that you can produce every string with $2k$ characters or less containing an equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s. Say you have a string $\omega$ with $2(k+1) = 2k+2$ characters, and for simplicity assume wlog that it starts with an $a$. Now look at all possible ways to write $\omega$ as $$
  \omega = a\omega_1b\omega_2
$$
Since $\omega$ contains at least one $b$ (it must, since it starts with an $a$), there's always at least one such pair $\omega_1,\omega_2$. *If* you can show that you can additionally require that both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ contain an equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s, youre done - both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are obviously at most $2k$ characters long, so by the induction hypothesis, you can produce them. You can then also produce $\omega$ by starting with the production $S \to aSbS$, followed by whatever you need to do to produce $\omega_1$ and then $\omega_2$.

The remaining question is, given a string $\omega$ starting with an $a$ and containing an equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s, can you always write it as $$
  a\omega_1b\omega_2
$$
such that both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ also contain an equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s?

Comment: I knew how to do the first part, but not the second part. the solution was explained in class, but the tutorial leader did a poor job explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answer(by fgp)
Let's define our word as $\omega = \alpha_0\alpha_1...\alpha_{2k+2}$

Let $d_i = N_a(i) - N_b(i)$ where

$N_a(i)$ - number of occurrences of the letter 'a' in a word  $\alpha_0\alpha_1...\alpha_{i}$

$N_b(i)$ - number of occurrences of the letter 'b' in a word  $\alpha_0\alpha_1...\alpha_{i}$

Let $j$ be the smallest index such that $d_j = 0$. Since $d_0 = 1$ (our word begins with letter 'a'), and since $d_{2k+2} = 0$, such index must exist.

Absolute difference between $d_i$ and $d_{i+1}$ is 1 for any $i = 0..2k+1$. Since $d_0 = 1$, all numbers in the set {$d_0$, $d_1$,..., $d_{j-1}$} are strictly positive, otherwise $j$ wouldn't be smallest such index where $d_j=0$. That demonstrates that $d_{j-1} = 1$ and that $\alpha_j = b$.

Finally, we hose $\omega_1 = \alpha_1\alpha_2...\alpha_{j-1}$ and $\omega_2 = \alpha_{j+1}\alpha_{j+2}...\alpha_{2k+2}$.

They both have equal number of letters 'a' and 'b' since $d(\omega_1)= d_{j-1} - d_0 = 0$ and $d(\omega_2) = d_{2k+2} - d_{j} = 0$, and it's easy to show that their lengths are $\leq 2k$.